# Navtitle element is not showing in pdf in Dita to pdf conversion by using oxygen

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, dita

How to make appear the element's content in pdf, while converting dita to pdf by using oxygen. My input xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "urn:pubid:com.brill.doctypes:doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_1">
   <title outputclass="title">LANDING GEARLANDING GEAR</title>
   <titlealts>
      <navtitle>FUNCTION, DATA FOR PLANS AND DESCRIPTION</navtitle>
   </titlealts>
   <prolog>
      <metadata>
         <data-about>
            <data type="data.module.code">HSXWB-A-79-11-11-00A01-000A-D</data>
            <data type="classification">01</data>
            <data type="responsible.partner.company">F0302</data>
            <data type="originator">F0302</data>
            <data type="applicability">ALL</data>
            <data type="data.module.reference.code">TRENTXWB-A-00-00-00-01A01-022A-D</data>
            <data type="quality.assurance">tabtop</data>
            <data type="skill.level">sk01</data>
            <data type="reason.for.update">First Release</data>
            <data type="publication.code">UNKNOWN PUBLICATION</data>
         </data-about>
         <foreign outputclass="issuenum">001</foreign>
         <unknown outputclass="date">2016-01-29</unknown>
      </metadata>
   </prolog>
   <body>
      <section>
         <title>DESCRIPTION</title>
         <p>The A380 is available with two types of turbofan engines, the
Rolls-Royce Trent 900 (variants A380-841, −842 and −843F) or the Engine
Alliance GP7000 (A380-861 and −863F).  Noise reduction was an important
requirement in the A380 design, and particularly affects engine design.</p>
         <p>Landing gears<ul>
               <li>
                  <p>Nose Landing Gear</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>Wing Landing Gear (Bogie Type, 4 Wheels  - 4 Braked)</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>Body Landing Gear (Bogie Type, 6 Wheels  - 4 Braked)</p>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </p>
      </section>
      <section>
         <title>Wing Landing Gear</title>
         <p>Each wing landing gear has a leg assembly and
a four-wheel bogie beam. The WLG leg includes a Bogie Trim Actuator
(BTA) and an oleo-pneumatic shock absorber.</p>
      </section>
      <section>
         <title>Body Landing Gear</title>
         <p>The two body landing gears have a six-wheel bogie
beam and a leg assembly that includes an oleo- pneumatic shock absorber.
A two-piece drag-stay assembly mechanically locks the leg in the extended
position.</p>
         <fig>
            <title>Landing gear</title>
            <image align="center" href="../ICN-HSXWB-A-791111-H-F0302-00001-A-001-01.tif"/>
         </fig>
      </section>
   </body>
</topic>
```

While I'm getting pdf, lot of elements are getting missing

converted pdf screenshot:
[image: converted pdf screenshot]

I want the navtitle element and meta data information with attribute value by using xslt. Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

it seems this is your first DITA customization. It be honest, what you want to do is not that easy as you probably expect. For achieving what you want, you should create a DITA-OT plugin, that overrides the default PDF-Plugin `org.dita.pdf2`. **You have to write XSLT code**! Please firstly read the [Customizing PDF output](http://www.dita-ot.org/2.3/dev_ref/pdf-customization.html) documentation of the DITA-OT. Then you should generate a PDF plugin stub using the [DITA-Generator](http://dita-generator.elovirta.com).

When you're done, call back. :)

Comment: Hi. thanks xephon. Its usefull. I have created customizing org.dita.pdf2 folder. But for the PDF Plugin Generator DITA OT version is having 2.2 and 2.3. But i want DITA OT 1.8.5. Is there is having any for this version?

Comment: Oh, the version has been removed? Hmm... I'll ask the developer, if an older version of the generator is available somewhere. But, if you can, you should upgrade the toolkit.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no older version available. You, unfortunately, have to build a plugin on your own, step-by-step, following the 1.8.5 docs.